# Why does express-ejs-layout fails to render layout.ejs?

Tags: express, layout, ejs

In the configuration below, the contents of `home.ejs` does not appear to get plugged into the `<%- body %>` of the `layout.ejs` page. Hitting the default route `/` returns the contents of the `home.ejs` with none of the structure or styling in `layout.ejs`.

I couldn't find any useful information to troubleshoot how `express-ejs-layouts` work. Any thoughts on why this might be?

#### App structure:

```
.
├── app
├── main.js
├── node_modules
├── package.json
└── public
    ├── css
    │   └── style.css
    ├── js
    │   └── app.js
    └── views
        ├── layout.ejs
        └── pages
            ├── events.ejs
            ├── home.ejs
            └── test.ejs
```

#### Configuration snippet:

```
// file: app/server.js

// template engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(expressLayouts);

// set views directory
app.set('views', __dirname + '/../public/views');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));
```

#### Route:

```
//file: app/controllers/mainController.js

exports.home = function(req,res){
    res.render('pages/home');
}
```

#### EJS files:

**layout.js (snippet)**

```
    <!--file: public/views/layout.ejs -->
...
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">

        ...

            <main id="site-main">
                <div class="container">
                    <%- body %>
                </div>
            </main>
...
```

**home.ejs**

```
<!--file: public/views/pages/home.ejs -->
    This is the home page
```

EDIT 1:

My example above didn't clearly highlight that i was declaring my route as `app.use('/',router)` before `use.app(expressLayouts)`. Swapping it around fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just set up a simple Express server using your file structure. If I request the home page from the client, I receive:

```
<main id="site-main">
    <div class="container">
        This is the home page
    </div>
</main>
```

This is what you want, right? The content of the `home.ejs` is included in the `layout.ejs`.

I wonder why it's not working for you. The simplified `server.js` I used (note no special routing file):

```
var express = require('express');
var expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(expressLayouts);

app.set('views', __dirname + '/../public/views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('pages/home');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

My dependencies in `package.json`:

```
{
  "ejs": "^2.5.2",
  "express": "^4.14.0",
  "express-ejs-layouts": "^2.2.0"
}
```

Tell me if that works for you, then we can research what's the problem with your configuration.

**EDIT:** Turned out that the OP put his route declaration `app.use('/',router);` before `app.use(expressLayouts);` That's why the `layout.ejs` was not considered for rendering.

Comment: So it looks like the issue was due to having my routes declaration `app.use('/',router);` before `app.use(expressLayouts);`. This wasn't clear in example code presented and I didn't realize how much of an impact the sequence can have.

Answer (score 3):

Set layout declaration just before the route declaration

Like this..

```
    //set the layouts
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(expressLayouts);

    //set the routes
    app.use(require('./app/routes'));
```